# jmeter: server response code is 400 even after passing all the required fields

Tags: jmeter

This is a simple API where I need to send data to the server by filling a form and in return, I get confirmation back from the server
https://snapmed.no/kontakt-1
I passed values such as craft_csrf_token and redirect to the request body. But, still, the server returns me a response code of 400
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLTV3.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYXZa.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrxlA.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6dQu.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJK0w.png

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it looks like in my browser:

[image]

So I think you need to tick `Use multipart/form-data` box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

If you have troubles in manually building correct HTTP requests the easier/faster/better option would be just recording the requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension:-Record-JMeter,-Selenium,-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

Comment: checked multipart/form-data and used a recorder for generating the script but still, response code is 400

Comment: Then you're not sending the same request as the browser does, make sure that JMeter is sending **absolutely** the same request (including [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)) apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) and you will get 200.